# ASP.NET MVC - Web Site and Web Service interaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The requirement requires a standard web site with a login form. Upon login the site redirects to a page where it prompts the user to "please insert your device". A separate application (a native app) will push the device id to some web service on the same server as the web site. The pushed device ID will be received by the web service and somehow it should be able to notify the web site so that it can turn redirect the "please insert your device" page to the main landing page. Is this possible and how? Thanks!

Comment: Sure - maybe investigate SingalR as a way of notifying the client page to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have different options:
- one is, like James S mentioned, to use something like [signalr](/questions/tagged/signalr)
- you can also do it manually, by keeping in mind that there is no permanent connection between the web client and your web server, your could show the message to insert the device and in background you ask via ajax and javascript/jQuery the webservice or the web application if the device a was inserted
- another way could be to show the message as a dialog, with a button which the user has to click when he inserted the device. When the user clicked OK I would check that the device was inserted and display the main page or an error message.